# USB keyboard not working after BIOS

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard

The USB will work in BIOS but once it gets past the BIOS window I'm left with the system restore and start windows but the keyboard will not work and goes straight to systems restore.

I have tried:

- 4 different keyboards
- All ports
- Different chassis

Comment: Sounds like a software issue where the USB controller is not initialised properly. Does the mouse work, or are you not even able to check that?

Comment: not able to check as it will not go past that screen
it works in bios

Comment: Does your computer has an old PS/2 (5pin din) connector for older keyboards? If so, you can get a convertor for ps/2 to usb to hook up your keyboard that way. It will then guarantee work and you can execute system restore which will likely correct the problem. If not, consider reinstalling windows.

Answer (score 0):

If USB keyboard works under BIOS, it means that USB host controller hardware is fully functional.

If the system proceeds to boot into OS and the USB does not work anymore, it means that the OS is corrupted and failed to proceed with loading USB driver. Maybe a 10-20 hours of Microsoft Professional work will help to restore your system, but the most practical way is to re-install the whole Windows thing from DVD media.